# Create check box form from rendered members to send email - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I've got a team members page which pulls through the users associated with a university sports club, I'm trying to get it to produce a check box next to each member so that a member of the committee can simply select several members and on pressing a submit button the system will send an email to them.

I tried `<%= check_box_tag(<%= render @users %>) %>` but didn't have any luck

**show_selection.html.rb** - This is the page that renders the users

```
<% if signed_in? %>
    <% if current_user.captain? %>
        Welcome, select members to send a message to below

    <table summary="Team members">
      <tr>
        <td class="main">
          <% unless @users.empty? %>
            <ul class="users">
              <%= render @users %>
            </ul>
            <%= will_paginate @users %>
          <% end %>
        </td>       
      </tr>
    </table>

    <br>
    <br>

<% else %>
    <h1>An error has occured</h1>
    <br>
    <p>It looks like you're trying to access a restricted page <%= link_to "Please Click Here", '/' %> </p>
    <% end %>
<% else %>
    An error has occured
    <br>
    <p>It looks like you're trying to access a restricted page <%= link_to "Please Click Here", '/' %> </p>
<% end %>
```

**users_contorller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate, :only => [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_filter :correct_user, :only => [:edit, :update]
  before_filter :admin_user,   :only => :destroy

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @microposts = @user.microposts.paginate(:page => params[:page])
    @title = @user.name
    @admins = User.where(:admin => "t")
    @captains = User.where(:captain => "t")
    @clubs = User.where(:captain => "t")
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
    @title = "Sign up"
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to University Sports!"
      redirect_to @user
      UserMailer.welcome_email(@user).deliver
    else
      @title = "Sign up"
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @title = "Edit user"
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated."
      redirect_to @user
    else
      @title = "Edit user"
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def index
    @users = User.paginate(:page => params[:page])
  end

  #def admins
  #  @users = User.admins
  #  render "users/index"
  #end

  def admins
    @admins=User.where(:admin => "t")
  end

  def captains
    @captains=User.where(:captain => "t")
  end

  def clubs
    @clubs=User.where(:captain => "t")
  end

  def destroy
    User.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "User destroyed."
    redirect_to users_path
  end

  def following
    @title = "Following"
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @users = @user.following.paginate(:page => params[:page])
    render 'show_follow'
  end

  def followers
    @title = "Followers"
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @users = @user.followers.paginate(:page => params[:page])
    render 'show_follow'
  end

  def selection
    @title = "Selection"
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @users = @user.followers.paginate(:page => params[:page])
    render 'show_selection'
  end 

  private

    def authenticate
      deny_access unless signed_in?
    end

    def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user?(@user)
    end

    def admin_user
      redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user.admin?
    end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you will need to wrap this in a form to handle the submission of the selected members to email.  The form should be posted to a mailer controller or an action to handle the selected members for emailing.

```
 <%= render @users %>
```

This will render a partial for each of the objects inside @users.   You should add the checkbox inside this partial in order to render it for each member.

You will have something like this in your partial

```
<%= check_box_tag "user_ids[]", user.id %>
```

Ryan has a railscast that will point you out the in right direction of how to implement.  This is about updating the records, but you can modify the code to work with your scenario.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/52-update-through-checkboxes